# Why are custom claims not updated when getting a new access token using a refresh token?

Tags: identityserver4

I have some code in my mobile app that calls the server to verify an email address with a 6 digit code that is emailed to the user. If the validation is successful I use the refresh token for the user to request a new access token. It appears that the custom claims are not updated in the new access token. I am specifically looking for an EmailVerified claim.

When I inspect the token before the validation call is made EmailVerified is false as is expected. When I inspect the newly retrieved access token it is still false even though in my server side database I can see that the value is true.

I thought at first I needed to revoke the access token so I added into my server side code a call to revoke it using RevokeAccessTokenAsync(). I can only guess that it works, there is no error but still the claims remain the same.

Is there some other setting that is caching this info somehow? I can't seem to track down what is causing it to not get updated. It is clearly a new token it just has stale information in it.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to configure the client:

> UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh
>
> ```
> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the access token
> (and its claims) should be updated on a refresh token request.
> ```

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html

Comment: You know I found this not too long after I posted, but its always like that. As soon as I post I find the answer. My problem was in my development environment I must have set that on the client by directly editing the database record but never added it to my config, so, when i rolled everything out to cloud servers it didnt get set and was driving me crazy. I thought I had a race condition at first because I was saving the token and then reading it and trying to use that value, anyway a simple fix. Thanks.